Retopologizing Hard Surface Model - Subdivision
I want to use subdivisions so I can smooth out a model I'm retopologizing for 3D printing as much as possible, however this is giving me trouble with the places I want to keep straight. For instance, this feature here:

In the retopologized model, it looks like this once the Subdivide modifier is applied:

(Ignore the inset area, I haven't gotten to the point of retopologizing that part yet).
And this is the mesh before the Subdivision modifier is applied:

As you can see, the front "point" has been truncated slightly (not too much of an issue) and the sharp edges of the back have been rounded (this is). I don't want to use Simple because the entire point is to smooth out the surface for printing.
I've tried adding extra edge loops around it, but that hasn't helped much. I've tried putting a Solidify and Bevel modifier before the Subdivide, but that just gets me this:

So my straight edges are there...but it's still putting the curve on top of it.
I don't want to use creases if I can avoid it, because then I have problems with this:

This is supposed to be a cylinder, but where there are multiple objects (such as landing gear doors or panels I want to be able to leave "open" on my printed model) the curve doesn't match up and it ends up as more of a slight lemon shape (it happens other places there are curved sections, including those WITHOUT multiple objects, but it's most noticeable here).

I may have found a partial work around to the cutout issue. I created a mesh from the cutout, and then used a Boolean Difference Modifier after the Subdivision and Solidify in the stack. The problem is I can't use Bevel Weights to bevel the edge of the cutout. Unless someone has a better idea of how to fix those corners.
